# Swift iOS14 DatePicker text alignment

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, ios14

I want my date picker to show the text right aligned as it is contained in an right aligned tableView. I'm using the iOS 14 default style were selecting the date picker ends up in a popover to select the date, so by default the label is left aligned when the popover is not showing.
I tried using `datePicker.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right` but nothing is changing.
Is there any other way to change the alignment as it is looking strange that way?
[image: DatePicker]

Comment: are you sure about your constraints ?

Comment: Constraints are set to all four sides, otherwise the grey rectangle would be different

Comment: For those looking to move the entire grey box area, you can right anchor the date picker and then call `.sizeToFit()` to set the width

Answer (score 15):

There's no explicit way to do this, since the widget itself seems to not honor the content alignment; **BUT**: I have found a way to do this that works with iOS *currently*. At some point the date picker creates a UILabel, seemingly with a 'leading' constraint, no matter what content alignment. But, we can override what that 'leading' means with clever use of `semanticContentAttribute`.

```
datePicker.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
datePicker.subviews.first?.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

1. This code can't crash the app, even if the widget changes, it safely access the first subview and sets an official API on it.
2. It does work with iOS 14.2; and
3. Supposing, in iOS 14.3 or 15+, Apple changes the widget structure such that this trick doesn't work, perhaps because there's another nested view, all that could happen is the layout goes back to the default.

It's possible only the second line of code is necessary, but my first attempt was with the first line, which didn't work, so I added the second line.

Comment: on iOS 14.5 it still doesn't work. In iOS 15.5+ it is aligned to right side by default (possibly it works on 15.0+). So you need to extract your code for iOS 14.x only