# UIDatePicker rendering is getting right aligned in Xcode 13 (iOS 15)

Tags: xcode, uidatepicker, ios15, xcode13

I compiled my app with **Xcode 13** and **iOS 15**, and I noticed the `UIDatePicker` is getting right aligned.

[image]

You can see that my storyboard is properly setup with constraints:

[image]

This UI element was working fine, even if I download the App Store version of my app on a device running iOS 15, it renders correctly. It's only compiling it with Xcode 13 that messes is up.

Is anyone else encountering that issue?

Comment: Having this issue as well on the public release of Xcode 13 :(

Comment: Yep! Same issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just a quick follow-up on this – I submitted this issue via Feedback Assistant and Apple told me this is expected behavior:

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this
> issue:
>
> This is intentional and not a bug. We right-align the UIDatePicker
> pills for compact. Please know that if you want to change the
> alignment of the UIDatePicker controls on iOS 15, we now support
> UIControl.contentHorizontalAlignment to do just that.

So the proper solution is as follows:

```
datePicker.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Comment: This also worked for me. However, you would think the control alignment setting in Xcode would do the same thing. It did not work for me without this line of code. iOS 17.

Comment: Worked for me, xcode 15 - iOS 17. Objective-C version: `self.datePicker.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;`

Answer (score 4):

The old behavior of the compact Date Picker (UIDatePicker) was aligned to left (with Xcode 12 + iOS 14), but now with Xcode 13 is aligned to right.

I ran into the same problem when using Xcode 13 and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402334/swift-ios14-datepicker-text-alignment).

```
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        // make date picker align to left in Xcode 13 with iOS 15
       datePicker.subviews.first?.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved it. I'm just a bit worried whether this is too fragile?

Comment: This solution technically works, but just as an FYI, it swaps the time and date fields (time appears to the left of the date, rather than on the right as it should).

Comment: I’m using the date only picker, so I didn’t notice that. It seems the ultimate solution is to wait Apple to let us customize the alignment of the datepicker…

Comment: I use date only, and this solution doesn't seem to work. Picker is left aligned, I'm trying to pin it to right.

Comment: Ah good catch @jwuki, just realized that the time is on the left side of the date. Not ideal. Maybe living with the whole thing right aligned is better? haha